# wp_get_post_terms isnt returning ACF values

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom taxonomy, I added 2 ACF fields to it, in the back end everything works great. But in the front end I cannot fetch the ACF values.

```
$context['bankingoptions'] = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'review_banking', array());
var_dump($context['bankingoptions']);
```

Will display below, notice there are no ACF values, there are 2: link(Page Link), icon(image)

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Term)[2220]
      public 'term_id' => int 73
      public 'name' => string 'Bitcoin' (length=7)
      public 'slug' => string 'bitcoin' (length=7)
      public 'term_group' => int 0
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 73
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'review_banking' (length=14)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => int 0
      public 'count' => int 1
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(WP_Term)[2222]
      public 'term_id' => int 74
      public 'name' => string 'Mastercard' (length=10)
      public 'slug' => string 'mastercard' (length=10)
      public 'term_group' => int 0
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 74
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'review_banking' (length=14)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => int 0
      public 'count' => int 1
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

Comment: Where in your code are you getting the ACF values? ACF values don't get attached to the `term_object` you get them by `get_field('field_name', term_object)`

Comment: Adding clarity to my last comment, ACF doesn't add `properties` to the WP_Term object. The data is stored in the `_taxonomymeta` table in the database.

Comment: @disinfor
At the moment I am not getting the ACF values, I assumed at first they would be returned wp_get_post_terms.. to complicate this even more I only fetch this info in a functions file and add it to .twig context, so i don't run php directly on my template that is displaying the content

Comment: so this $context['bankingoptions'] = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'review_banking', array()); is working and getting the basic taxonomy. I can loop through that in my .twig template and it works, but I can't run a PHP  get_field() there, that needs to be fetched and added to wp_get_post_terms array from the functions file. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Couldn't you just create a function that returns what you desire, instead of only using wp_get_post_terms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the acf in taxonomy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887090/how-to-access-the-acf-in-taxonomy)

Answer (score 1):

If you accessing ACF fields anywhere out of taxonomy pages then your code will be as below

Syntax -

```
$field = get_field('field_name', $taxonomy_slug . '_' . $taxonomy_term_id);
```

Eg. -

```
$field = get_field('field_name', 'review_banking_123');
```

Comment: Thanks again,

after i fetch the taxonomy array, I will need to loop through it to fetch the ACF data, using your sample code how do i get the var $taxonomy_term_id


$arr = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'review_banking', array());
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $field = get_field('link', $taxonomy_slug . '_' . $taxonomy_term_id);
    var_dump($value);
}

Answer (score 1):

@disinfor, your first response is the answer, this gets my data

```
$arr = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'review_banking', array());
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $icon = get_field('icon', $value);
    $link = get_field('link', $value);
    var_dump($icon);
    var_dump($link);
}
```